# Как решить ошибки при запуске миграций?

Tags: composer, php7, laravel-5.7

После команды `php artisan migrate --seed`

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : syntax error, unexpe
>   cted ';', expecting ',' or ')'  at D:\ASITES\corporate.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Co
>   nnection.php:454

```
  */
    public function statement($query, $bindings = [])
    {
        return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($query, $bindings) {
            if ($this->pretending()) {
                return true;
            }

            $statement = $this->getPdo()->prepare($query);

  /*454*/   $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings);

            $this->recordsHaveBeenModified();

            return $statement->execute();
        });
    }




**454 стр>**  $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings);


  Exception trace:
 1   Composer\Autoload\includeFile("D:\ASITES\corporate.loc\vendor\composer/../
laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php")
      D:\ASITES\corporate.loc\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322

  2   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass("Illuminate\Database\Connection")
      [internal]:0
```

Comment: Вам же пишут, что скобки закрывающей не хватает. Вам IDE не подсвечивет это место как ошибку? Не подчеркивает? Или вы в блокноте пишите?

Comment: Сниппеты предназначены для запуска javascript кода в теле вопроса, для простого форматирования кода используйте «Пример кода»

Comment: Не стоит менять вопрос на вновь возникший, в этом случае следует задавать новый вопрос.

Comment: vp_arth так ошибка не исчезла и  public function statement не отрабатывает на 458 стр.

Comment: Это **другая** ошибка. Была синтаксическая в php, теперь ошибка в схеме базы. Не стейняйтесь [задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) столько вопросов, сколько у вас возникает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings);
> ```

В этой строке 2 открывающих скобки и только одна закрывающая.
Добавьте пропущенную.

Comment: это я уже нашел, но cmd все ровно ругается  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 7
sers_email_unique`(`email`)) где эту скобку убрать бы ещё..на 458 стр Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes") и  PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: Это абсолютно другой вопрос, закройте этот (зеленая галка на ответе), вернув ему первоначальную форму и задайте новый.